# cannot select a row based on certain string

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have been trying to select rows of a column in a dataset based on a string, named 'Gemeente', the dutch translation of municipality.

I have used the following code to select it.

```
select * from incomecbs where regioaanduiding = 'Gemeente'
```

In this case, regioaanduiding means region'.

[image]

Unfortunately i get no results when doing this.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!But without seeing your data and table structure it's impossible to say what the problem is. Maybe the string is actually GEMEENTE in the database. It is also possible that the column `regioaanduiding` is actually a foreign-key reference to another lookup table, used to ensure that only known strings are stored in that column. Show us at least the structure of table `incomecbs`. You should [edit] your question to include it, *as text, not a picture*; together with some sample data from the table.

Comment: Can you try select * from incomecbs where regioaanduiding like 'Gemeente%'

Comment: What you are trying is correct, issue may be there is some space at the end of Gemeente. other than that i can't see any issue

Comment: Thx! Can you try select * from incomecbs where regioaanduiding like 'Gemeente%' – 
ishant kaushik
 4 mins ago this one worked for me !!

Comment: great I am adding this to solution.So that if anyone else face this can find it useful

Answer (score 0):

There may be trailing spaces in your data. Try using `like`:

```
select * from incomecbs where regioaanduiding like 'Gemeente%'
```

Keep in mind that this may perform poorly on large tables compared to strict equality.